# Is it possible to use cf event as an input in logstash?

Tags: logstash, cloud-foundry

I'd like to get the following system: once an event occurs in Cloud Foundry, it is loaded to elasticsearch. Using logstash would be fine, but I explored its input plugin and couldn't find anything that I could use. What is the best solution for this scenario? At the moment I can think of writing a script that would continuously pull the data using CF api and load it to elasticsearch. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions:

1. Create a "drain" (e.g., via the [drain CLI](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-drain-cli)) for the app you
   would like to see events for and drain it to your ELK deployment.
   This should forward each event (formatted as rfc 5425 syslog) to
   elastic search.
2. If you are using the Loggregator Firehose to write data into elastic
   search (e.g., via [firehose-to-syslog](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/firehose-to-syslog)) then you will get events
   (as log messages). This has the downside of everything ends up in
   your ELK deployment.

Comment: As far as I understand these are the solutions for tracking apps logs. By events I mean not logs but events that can be pulled from cf api /v2/events route (app started, stopped, crashed, etc.)

Comment: If you watch cf logs you will notice those come out as well from your app stream. Having only events drain though is a cool idea, I can speak with the PM.